# Modularity vs Antipode In the category $Bord^{\operatorname{or}}_{1,2,3}$

Tags: category-theory, mathematical-physics, low-dimensional-topology, hopf-algebras

Supposedly the category  $Bord^{\operatorname{or}}_{1,2,3}$ carries with it the structure of a Hopf algebra.  If that's the case I would like to understand what the antipode is.

To that end, I've been reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.06811.pdf).  On page 19 diagram 36 seems to be similar to that of the antipode relation of a Hopf algebra however it is called the modularity condition in the paper.  The antipode relation is shown as the very first diagram [at this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_algebra).

So, my question is, how are the modularity relation and the antipode related?